# How to store this kind of graph?

Tags: c++, coding-style, stl

Suppose we have a graph with bidirectional edges, no weights. How can I store it so that I don't waste tons of memory, make it fast and have a fast access to every vertex's neighbors? I mean, until now for sth like this: `{(1,2)(1,5)(1,3)(2,4)(2,3)}` I have been using an array: `array[1][2]=1` meaning that there is a connection between 1 and 2. There are two problems with that:

- a) as the graph is bidirectional, `(1,2)` means `(2,1)` exists as well. If I want to have easy access to 2's neighbors later, I have to make two changes per iteration: `array[1][2]=1`, `array[2][1]=1`
- b) when I know some vertex (say 5) has only one neighbor left, I have to search through the whole `array[5][x]` checking every possible `x`
- c) for a graph of a million vertexes, this monster becomes too vast to be used in any competition

Could you please help me and point me the solution to my problems?

Comment: Is this for homework? If so, please tag it as such!

Comment: There is always [Boost.Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html).

Comment: Rob - would rather stay with STL things, such fancy libraries usually aren't allowed on any competitions and such.

Comment: Graphs are all about trade offs. For your case, sparse matrices would be fine to me. Other suggested answers will do, but be sure to understand the STL collections to figure out yourself what structure you need in term of memory usage, access to vertices, to adjacency lists, etc. If you are even half serious about C++ and graphs, please have a look at the Boost Graph Library to see how these folks approach graph algorithms generically in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want a map of sets.

`std::map< int, std::set< int > >`

So for an int you can store a collection of all its neighbours in the set. You will want functions to manipulate this collection.

If the number of nodes is countable, i.e. they range from 0 to N and include all these numbers then you can use `std::vector< std::set<int> >` and it would be more efficient to do so. You could also use `std::vector< std::bitset<N> >` or `std::vector< boost::dynamic_bitset > >` if you have, say, 20,000 nodes and can therefore afford 20,000 bitsets of 2500 bytes (plus a bit of overhead) each  = 50MB of memory (approx).

This is a slightly more compact model to the one you have but not by a lot. If you have a million vertices it will be about 125GB so obviously you can't use this model but should use the set. Also, iterating through a vertex to see what its neighbours are is a much faster operation with a set than a bitset.

Unless there are many vertices with no neighbours at all though and that they are sequentially numbered, there is no advantage of map over vector though.

Not sure how much memory you call "tons". The model I just outlaid uses constant memory whereas the map of sets uses memory proportional to the number of neighbourhood-relationships you have but as it gets full will be far less compact than the vector of bitsets so will consume more.

Comment: Seems rather complicated for my current skills but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a triangular matrix. This means that, say, if x < y, then (x, y) will exist but (y, x) will not -- and you will find the corresponding value at (x, y).

See http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/algorithms/general/article.php/c11211 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305186/isolating-triangle-array-items-and-evaluating-them-for-equality-then-outputting for examples.